# Bubble events up through canvas shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, events, shapes

Let's assume a shape has been created and added to a canvas. An event handler can be added for let's say a left mouse button up event like this:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle r = new Rectangle(...);
r += r_MouseLeftButtonUp;
// Maybe other event handlers added...
Canvas.Children.Add(r);
```

So this works great. The event handler is fired except when another shape is created on the same canvas overlapping the first shape. Is there any way to fire up the mouseLeftButtonUp event through all shapes under the mouse cursor position?

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping should work as long as there is a clickable portion available for any shape. If the issue here is about the shape that becomes hidden because of another shape on top of it (no longer clickable) you can call your handler using the Canvas.

```
<Canvas UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUp="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rec1" Height="50" Width="50" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Fill="Aqua"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rec2" Height="50" Width="50" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="25" Fill="LightBlue"/>
 </Canvas>
```

That would set up the EventHandler when you left click the Canvas. And we can invoke the handler on each Shape child of the canvas.

```
 private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
        Canvas c = sender as Canvas;
        foreach (Rectangle r in c.Children)
        {
           // Invoke the handler here...
        }
  }
```

Comment: There are two problems with this approach. One, I don't want to fire the event just for the rectangles, but for any shape under the mouse cursor. Ellipses, polylines, you name it. Two, I would need an additional if for each shape to check if it is under the mouse cursor. I want to drift away from this approach because it feels heavy and encumbered.

Comment: The iteration on rectangle children is just a concept. You can get the mouse coordinate and limit the calls to which got hit and those that intersect. And you can apply it to any children as long as it is of type UIElement. It looks like you want to route the event within siblings in which the built in routing is not designed for - it calls for a work around OR go to custom routed events.